# Check for any ongoing background API calls to finish in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, watch, restangular

My AngularJS controller is calling an API to get a list of members. The API can be queried with multiple filters, like age range, name search, zipcode, etc.

What I am trying to accomplish is to make the user feel like the search is really fast. So while the user is filtering, I am $watch'ing the filters for changes. When a filter changes I immediately do a new search API call, instead of waiting for the user to click "search".

The idea is that when the user finishes filtering and clicks "search", the system should already be finished searching and can just output the search results.

**The problem:** When a user clicks "search" and the `publish()` function is called, I have to make sure that no API search is currently ongoing and if one is, wait for it to finish. I then publish the search results from the hidden `memberslist.temp` to the visible `memberslist.members`.

```js
// Current code works, except the publish function. See the TODO:

app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', '$timeout', function($scope, Restangular, $timeout) {

    // Pushes prefetched search results over to the visible search results
    // TODO: Check if search is ongoing...
    $scope.publish = function() {
        $scope.memberslist.members = $scope.memberslist.temp;
    };

    // Watch filters for changes
    var searchTimer    = false;
    var previousSearch = [$scope.name, $scope.minAge, $scope.maxAge];

    $scope.$watch('[name, minAge, maxAge]', function(newVal, oldVal, scope){
        if (searchTimer) {
            $timeout.cancel(searchTimer);
        }  

        // Do search only after the user has stopped typing for 400 ms
        searchTimer = $timeout(function(){
            if (!_.isEqual(newVal, previousSearch)) {
                previousSearch = newVal;
                scope.search();
            }
        }, 400);
    }, true);

    $scope.search = function() {
        var query_params = {
            name:        $scope.name, 
            price_min:   $scope.minAge,
            price_max:   $scope.maxAge
        };

        Restangular.all('members').getList(query_params)
            .then(function(members){
                $scope.memberslist.temp = members;
            });
    };
}]);
```

My first thought was to set a variable like isSearching = true, then set that back to false once the search call returns it's results. Can't seem to get it to work though.

Comment: Why don't you look at angularui typeahead http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks for chiming in :) Typeahead will display a list of hits using the promise of the call to the datastore as a trigger to update the list. My problem here is a bit similar, but not quite: Imagine if typeahead have a button that said "Load search results", which then had to check if there was an ongoing search or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
$scope.$watch('!is_searching && publishing', function(newVal){
  if (newVal) {
    $scope.memberslist.members = $scope.memberslist.temp;
    $scope.publishing = false;
  }
})
```

Set "is_searching" to true on the scope when the search starts, and set it to false when it is done. Set "publishing" on the scope when the search button is clicked.

That should give you the desired behavior. Publish right away if no search is running, otherwise wait until search is complete.

Comment: Excellent :) Works like a charm. In all honesty though: Am I not dumping too much code into my controller? Very kind of you not to mention that ;)

Comment: Well yes, lots of stuff could be moved around. Search could be a service and the whole "activate after 400ms of not typing" could be a directive so you never even have to touch your controller with that bit. Things can always get cleaner :)

Comment: Interesting! I am in the process of setting up the service, but how would you set up the "activate after 400ms" directive? (it would be the third directive of my short Angular career :)

Comment: I would create a directive that takes an expression (something like <input while-typing="search()" />) that binds to keyup and paste. Then when triggered it runs your above logic to delay until the user has stopped typing, then it triggers the expression (scope.$eval(attrs.whileTyping)). The result is a directive that can run any arbitrary function from the scope, or other expressions, while you type, with reasonable intervals.

Comment: So the directive waits for you to start typing, then activates any given expression after you have stopped. It knows nothing about the search itself, it only handles the delay and then triggers a function from the scope, so it is reusable for other things as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the input!

I made an attempt at this, and it works, although perhaps not very elegant :) Looks like this: http://paste.laravel.com/OJU. What do you think?

I check the value too, so that I only run the function if the value actually changes, and not on keyup on the shift key for instance.

Plus I use scope.$apply, not scope.$eval.

And I'm just binding to keyup. Is there a paste event too?

Comment: Nice, looks good. I think it's very clean and easy to read which is the most important part :). Yes, there is a paste event that you can bind to. It triggers when you mouse right-click > paste. Not sure that all browsers will recognize that event, but it is a nice touch for those that do and it's easy to add.